# Grouped notification email workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online

I was wondering if anyone could possibly help me with my SharePoint 2010 issue. I recently created a CRM System within SharePoint for my small business which utilizes a email notification workflow. The workflow is triggered when the 'Action Needed' field has a 'yes' value, this means that 2 days after the information is created or edited the workflow will notify the particular user that further action is needed.

[image: Email notification Workflow]

Now this is great if myself or other members of the team are only inputting a couple of items but I found out the hard way when i keyed in 20 or so items and received 20 individual emails which is irritating as you can imagine.

So on to my issue, I would like the email notifications to be grouped together in one email so it's more efficient and avoids the need for individual emails. So when one particular user creates or edits multiple records instead of separate email notifications I would like it all in one email. So is this possible while using SharePoint workflows? If it is possible andhow would i go about expanding my current workflow to incorporate this feature?

Thanks to anyone who contributes and helps me with my problem.